# Calling Haskell library from C++

Tags: c++, api, haskell, interface, ffi

I'm building an application in `Qt` (`C++`) which uses library written in Haskell as a backend. How can I export interface of `Haskell` library to `C++`?

When functions in haskell library are using simple types like `int` or `float` it's not a problem but what when they use structures as an arguments? What is the most scalable solution in this case?

Comment: What about doing IPC with a [UNIX domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)?

Comment: IPC needs marshalling on both sides. Thats the some kind of solution, but it still requires much work and is not efficient as it could be.

Comment: I didn't try it, but it could be usefull for you: https://github.com/wavewave/fficxx

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for calling c++ from Haskell. Not what I'm looking for, but thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write haskell code to marshal those datastructures into ones you can use in Haskell. The c2hs tool is very helpful in this regard: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hs

While the tool *appears* to be designed for calling C from Haskell, it is also very useful for the opposite in one sense -- it allows you to marshall complex C types into Haskell types. Since the functions you expose will need to take C types (typically pointers to complex structures), then you can A) construct appropriate C structures, and B) use the features c2hs provides in order to then marshall those structures into Haskell in your exposed functions, so that you can work with them.

Also note that with c2hs style generated tools, you don't need to marshall everything. You can just generate accessors to peek into the parts of C data structures that you actually care about.

Comment: Hum, actually, he want to generate C headers/wraping to call haskell functions from C++ code. Not to write haskell binding of C++ code. I think you've read the converse.

Comment: That's good point, but I still hope that there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: Well C can't access Haskell data structures, because they include thunks, etc. and so are generally tied to the runtime. That means your Haskell necessarily needs a wrapper layer letting it interact with c structures in some fashion. Without more details on what you want to do, that's the best advice I can give. With a more specific question I could provide more guidance.

Comment: Okay, I will try this tomorrow. Thank you very much for your advice, I will report my results soon ;)

Comment: Another idea could be to figure out how to call your GUI code from Haskell, making the Haskell both the front and back ends with C++ just used for UI.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but I think you want to use this:

- http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html

Specifically something like `foreign export ccall foo :: Int -> IO Int`.  Which will generate a header such as:

```
#include "HsFFI.h"
extern HsInt foo(HsInt a0);
```

See the link for more details (such as how to integrate into your C++ program).

Comment: This answer adds nothing to what the OP said he knows how to do, especially it doesn't explain how to handle complex structures.